# Как правильно использовать dotenv в php

Tags: php, composer, .env

Я установил библиотеку с помощью composer, она подключилась, но при попытке использования ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Dotenv\Dotenv::__construct() must be an instance of Dotenv\Loader\LoaderInterface, string given.

Вот код:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

Файл .env есть. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А чем вам [документация](https://github.com/symfony/dotenv) не подходит? Опять же, будьте конкретны и указывайте какую библиотеку вы используете так как есть одна Симфонеевская, а другая - от [vlucas](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv::createMutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

Comment: unexpected 'createMutable' (T_STRING), вот такая ошибка.